# how to make the sound of a metallic spring

Tags: foley

I want to make the sound of spring I want it to be a little comic? IS there a material which I can make the sound?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the traditional "boing"-sound, it's a box with a string and pretty tricky to make yourself, though far from impossible. Another way is a normal Jew's Harp.

Jew's harp:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jew%27s_harp

Boing Box:
http://bizarrelabs.com/boing2.htm